# Action Required: S3 shutting down legacy application server capacity

Tags: amazon-s3

I got a mail from amazon s3 webservices stating below details

"We are writing to you today to let you know about changes which impact your use of the Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3). In efforts to best serve our customers, we have improved the systems powering the Amazon S3 API and are in the process of shutting down legacy application server capacity. We have detected access on the legacy capacity for Amazon S3 buckets that you own. The legacy capacity is no longer in service, as the DNS entry for the S3 endpoint no longer includes the IP addresses associated with it. We will be shutting down the legacy capacity and retiring the set of IP addresses fronting this capacity after April 1, 2020."

I want to find out which legacy system I am using, and how to prevent from affecting my services.

Comment: Did you try reading about legacy DNS names being deprecated befoe asking this question? Knowing AWS I would expect that they have links to references in the e-mail they sent. Have you read those?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes clicked the reference given in mail. It is redirecting me to personal health dashboard, here i can find this below details s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, 
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12739.94.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.137 Safari/537.36 and 
152.26.208.33,    but when click on it, is redirecting to bucket list. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you had a web site, www.example.com.

In DNS, that name was pointed to your web server at 203.0.113.100.

You decide to buy a new web server, and you give it a new IP address, let's say 203.0.113.222.

You update the DNS for example.com to point to 203.0.113.222.  Within seconds, traffic starts arriving at the new server.  Over the coming minutes, more and more traffic arrives at the new server, and less and less arrives at the old server.

Yet, for some strange reason, a few of your site's prior visitors are still hitting that old server.  You check the DNS and it's correct.  Days go by, then weeks, and somehow a few visitors who used your old server before the cutover are still hitting it.

How is that possible?

That's the gist of the communication here from AWS.  They see your traffic arriving on unexpected S3 server IP addresses, for no reason that they can explain.

You're trying to connect to the right endpoint -- that's not the issue -- the problem is that for some reason you have somehow "cached" (using the term in a very imprecise sense) an old DNS lookup and are accessing a bucket by hitting a wrong, old S3 IP address.

If you have a Java backend service accessing S3, those can notorious for holding on to DNS lookups forever.  You might need to restart that service, and look into how to resolve that issue and enable correct behavior which is -- as I understand it -- not how Java behaves by default.  (Not claiming to be a Java expert but I've encountered this sort of DNS behavior many times.)

If you have an HAProxy or Nginx server that's front-ending for an S3 bucket and has been up for a while, those might need a restart and you should look into how to correctly configure them not to resolve DNS only at startup.  I ran into exactly this issue once, years ago, except my HAProxy was forwarding requests to Amazon CloudFront on only 1 of the several IP addresses it could have been using.  They took that CloudFront edge server offline, or it failed, or whatever, and the DNS was updated... but my proxy was not able to re-query DNS so it just kept trying and failing until I restarted it.  Then I fixed it so that it periodically repeated the DNS lookup so it always had a current address.

If you have your own DNS resolver servers, you might want to verify that they aren't somehow misbehaving, and you might want to ensure that you don't for some reason have any `/etc/hosts` (or equivalent) static host entried for anything related to S3.

There could be any number of causes but I'm confident at least in my interpretation of what they say is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, let me follow your suggestion and see what happens.